# How to extract the first two digits from the right side of decimal point?

Tags: excel

In this example, I am attempting to extract the digits, "**44**", from "**2330.44**".

Subtracting the truncated value, "2330", from the original value gives me one form of this (see photo below - Cell reference I14 holds the value, "2330.44"). However, this is not what I am looking for.

[image]

Is there a way to either:

A) Remove the "0" and "." from "0.44".

B) Extract first two digits after decimal point more efficiently.

Comment: Use `MOD` Function

Comment: `=TRUNC(MOD(I14,1)*100)` (mistakenly used `ROUND` earlier).

Comment: The day that Microsoft adds a `StrTok()` function to excel will be a happy day indeed.

Comment: @JNevill Sir, truly!!!

Comment: @BigBen Sir, the one with `ROUND` worked as well!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - for the sample data it did, but it would mistakenly return 45 for an input of 2330.445 for example. `TRUNC` should be used, not `ROUND`.

Comment: @BigBen Sir, ah yes correct sir, agreed!

Comment: @BigBen Sir, thank you since you have highlighted, then the formulas i suggested will be • `=--LEFT(REPLACE(B1,1,FIND(".",B1),""),2)` • `=--LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B1,QUOTIENT(B1,1)&".",""),2)` • `=--LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B1,INT(B1)&".",""),2)`

Comment: Thank you very much BigBen and Mayukh Bhattacharya, it seems there are several methods of accomplishing this! If either one of you would like the credit, kindly post your solution as an answer so I can mark this thread as resolved.

Comment: @BigBen Sir, please post your solution as an answer, its simple & elegant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options, including using `MOD` and `TRUNC`:

```
=TRUNC(MOD(I14,1)*100)
```